# Querying For Top Seller

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, react

I hope you guys are all doing great and staying safe.

I am in the process of completing a project and the last thing im struggling with is querying the contract for the items sold and comparing to see which address has sold the most items.

Can someone possibly provide a potential way to go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can generate an event for each operation then use a script to filter operations.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the response! Can you possibly provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have an example available. If shouldn't be too hard to write one, so I encourage you to start subscribing to events and ask here if something doesn't work.